# Xtend does not seem to recognize += -=

Tags: xtend

I am using the full eclipse package from the Xtend website. I am able to create Xtend classes and they compile just fine except that Xtend does not seem to recognize the operators += or -=. These operators result in a compilation error (such as: += cannot be resolved). The editor also does not seem to recognize them. Are these operators valid in Xtend? They are listed in the official documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share an example. += and -= are for lists only afaik

Comment: same here ie.:
var dmg = 0;
dmg += 2;
"+= cannot be resolved" This is a pity, because I used it a lot in java

Answer (score 2):

They fixed that in X-tend 2.6.0. So just install the latest version.
 Here is the udpate site for convenience: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/